# 301 redirect folder with ~ syntax

Tags: redirect, directory, litespeed

My site is running on a Litespeed web server, the problem is domain.ltd/~username/ working like a mirror of domain.ltd/

Please help me to redirect all the URL domain.ltd/~username/* to domain.ltd/*

Thank you!